# How can I execute formular which I insert by VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some code and have a question.

I sucessfully make macro which insert formular into cell.

Problem is It is not working automatically.

```
Function test(PCell As Range) As String
    test = Chr(61) & Replace(PCell.Address, "$", "")
End Function
```

Cell shows `=N3` (simple example). And I can execute Push "F2" - "Enter". It is working well.

Problem is .. There are more than 100 cells. If there is no solution, I have to push F2 - Enter 100 hundred times.

After select the cells, How can I execute the formular in cells? or by using VBA?

I tried to use Selection.Evaluate() But there is nothing happened. And "F9" key is also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a faster and simpler way to achive this result.

```
'''vba
Sub ExecuteBulkFormula(SrcRng as Range,TgtRng as Range)
'What this procedure does is it loops through every area in the
'SrcRng and then loops through every cell in this area

'It then writes the formula in the array

'i: Loop Counter

'arr_index: Array Items Counter

'r_area: Every range contains atleast one Area as a Range Object
'The usage of Area is essential, as sometimes if we select multiple
'areas, For Example: A1:C2 & A5:C6, Then we can access these two "areas"

'The screenshot for the areas is added below (Figure 1).
'If however, we don't use Areas then we can only access the first Area
'i.e. A1:C2


Dim i as Long, arr_index as long
Dim r_area as Range
Dim arr as Variant

Redim arr(1 To 1000)
arr_index = 1

For Each r_area In SrcRng.Areas
  For i = 1 to r_area.count
    'Just Replace the below line to change the formula to fit your needs
    arr(arr_index) = Chr(61) & Replace(r_area(i).Address, "$", "")
    arr_index = arr_index+1
  Next i
Next

Redim Preserve arr(1 To arr_index)
TgtRng.Formula = arr

End Sub
```

Figure 1

[image: Range Areas Example]

**How to use this function?**

1. In excel worksheet, press Alt+F11 or Developer Tab->Visual Basic
   Right Click in any item in Project Explorer and then select Insert->Module
2. In this module, insert this above code.
3. To run this code you can use the immediate window (Ctrl+G) or write another procedure to run this code.

**Suggestions**

Instead of using `Replace` you can use `Range.AddressLocal(False,False)`
It will produce the same result.

This function `ExecuteBulkFormula` will run very fast

For 1000 rows: 0.016 sec (or 16 milliseconds)

For Reference my laptop is dual core i7-5500u which is low end.

Answer (score 0):

to have function calculate at every sheet change, just add `Application.Volatile` (see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile)

```
Function test(PCell As Range) As String
   Application.volatile
   test = Chr(61) & Replace(PCell.Address, "$", "")
End Function
```

to place that cell in all cells of a given range:

```
Sub PlaceTest()
    With Range("A1:A10") ' change the range address to to fit your needs
        .Formula = "=test(RC[1])" ' this will feed the function with the cell 1 column to the right of where the function is placed: just play around with R1C1 notation (https://excelchamps.com/formulas/r1c1/) 
    End With
End Sub
```